# DEBUG how to display, increment, loop in a cmd debug environment

Tags: debugging, assembly, loops, increment, tasm

```
a 0100
mov cx,59
mov ah,02
mov dl,20
int 21
inc dl
loop 0105
int 20

g
```

i am trying to loop and increment the value in DL but when i run it .it does not show anyting or rather it shows the 'space' character only
.i wanted to do this on DEBUG environment so please don't tell me to use TASM xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your loop instruction, because right now it resets dl with 20h, that's why it prints only the space character. Try looping directly on the int 21h instruction.

Comment: actually loop 0105 loops it to the mov dl,20 address which displays the 20h character (space) .all i wanted is to loop and increment it. which i already did (without the incrementing)

Comment: @kapitanluffy: if 0105 is an address I don't think it's correct. Anyway, the loop instructions decrements cx and if it's not 0 it continues the loop. So probably that's why your program doesn't print.

Comment: try replacing value of dl into 21 and it will print exclamation points 59 times i think

Comment: @kapitanluffy: yep. It should, but then don't increment dl.

Comment: but that's what i need to do. i need to increment it xD any other suggestions?

Comment: @kapitanluffy: yep. if loop 0105 jumps to mov dl,20 the dos will print always the space, because when you call it dl contains always 20h. try loop directly on the int 21h ;)

Comment: i love you blackbear <3 haha thanks thanks sorry i actually don't fully understand every line there .int 21h is? display character? or something?

Comment: @kapitanluffy: you are welcome! xD well, int 21h is an interrupt, it calls the dos. it can do some low-level things, check here: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html

Comment: oh ok on to the next problem .displaying the hex values of each lol .btw try posting your answer here so i can click the check on it xD

Comment: @kapitanluffy: edited, thanks. ;) that's much more complicated, because you have to convert each character number to a string. You look like a beginner, so have a look at this: http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AsmTools/MASM/stdlib/stdlibv1.html

Comment: It's a sort of stdio.h but for assembly. it helped me a lot when I was learning! actually I'm still using it. =P

Comment: @kapitanluffy: hey, I didn't want to offend you!